# How to get content of Map object in JS template literal in readable format?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-map

Let's say I have a Map:

`const m = new Map([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]);`

**What's the quickest method to inline it in template literal in a manner that it will look like this:**

[image]

**or any other readable format?**

P.S. This won't work:

```
const str = `${m}`;
```

Comment: I don't get it. What you showed us is exactly what `console.log(m)` displays.

Comment: @Zenoo updating question.

Comment: @Zenoo please view now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a function for it, which takes the map and creates a string.

```js
function beautify(o) {
    if (o instanceof Map) {
        return 'Map(' + JSON.stringify(Array.from(o.entries())) + ')';
    }
    return o;
}


const m = new Map([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]);
console.log(beautify(m));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've extracted needed part to other answer. Upvoting yours answer as it's more universal.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320666/2730688) answer, I would go with either with

```
console.log(` something => ${JSON.stringify([...m])}`);
```

or with

```
console.log(` something => ${JSON.stringify(Array.from(m))}`);
```